# How to create web service on Sitecore Paas

Tags: azure, sitecore-services-client

I have Sitecore on Azure "Paas". I need to expose some Sitecore functionality to external system, for example allow external system to create Sitecore item.

Normally I would create a web service for this, but since its Sitecore on Azure I am not sure. I believe this might be handled with Sitecore client API but not really sure what solution to look for.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

You can still create web services using Azure Platform Services, including:

1. **Azure Functions** with HTTP Trigger will enable you to make external Web service calls and Functions can then make API calls to Sitecore.
2. Use **API Gateway** to enable metered and secured access if you have multiple clients that require tracking and throttling of usage.
3. Or **Azure API Apps** provides hosting for API that is closest to the traditional "Web Services" project build in VS.

In all of the options above, you can leverage Sitecore APIs the same way you would if you had Sitecore hosted on-prem.

References:

- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/
- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/api/

Comment: thanks, what about WebApi service or MVC routing, can they be used in a similar way?

Comment: @SaadAlam Yes, you can still do that just as you would with Sitecore hosted on any other platform.

Answer (score 2):

If your question is what is the best approach to allow external resources to interact with Sitecore, and not about how to create a web service:

I wouldn't re-invent the wheel. If you just need to expose Sitecore's functionality, just use Sitecore's functionality.

Sitecore already exposes its [API](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/sitecoreservicesclient/the_restful_api_for_the_itemservice) with CRUD operations, including search: For the requirements you are mentioning, no need to create custom web services.

Answer (score 1):

A fourth option would be to create a WebAPI / MVC controller in your Sitecore solution (a new feature if you use a Helix/Habitat approach).

- [MVC routing in Sitecore](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/mvc/use_mvc_routing)